# Shotwell: Shortcut for moving between events?

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I'm browsing through a year's worth of photos in Shotwell. The photos are automatically sorted into events by date (which I like). Whenever I open an event, I can highlight a photo and use the arrow keys to scroll through the event. I can also double click to open the photo and jump to the next using the arrow keys.

But is there any way to use the keyboard to jump to the next/previous event when I'm done looking at the current event?

The best I can come up with is 2x Shift-Tab to highlight the side pane, use the arrow keys, and then 2x Tab to jump back to the pictures. Not very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Such shortcut key is not available. A shortcut key to move down or up a folder/event/saved search vrom within the viewing pane certainly would enhance keyboard navigation, and would constitute a valid feature request.

Comment: Thanks :-) I went so far as to downloading the source yesterday to check if I could figure out how to add it myself, but it was not immediately obvious after poking around for half an hour. I'll consider making a feature request.

Comment: Similarly, once you do a search, then look at a picture in the results, there is no single-key way to return to the results.

Comment: @vanadium Sorry, completely forgot. Accepted now :-)